# Python Aggregate sum over dataframe with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
stuff datetime value
A 1/1/2019 3
A 1/2/2019 4
A 1/3/2019 5
A 1/4/2019 6
...
```

I want to create a new dataframe that looks like this:

```
stuff avg_3 avg_4 avg_5
A 3.4 4.5 5.5
B 2.3 4.2 6.1
```

where avg_3 is the avg of the last 3 days from today, avg_4 is the avg of the last 4 days from today etc grouped by stuff

How do I do that?

My current code:

```
df.groupby('stuff').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(dict(
    day_3=(x.datetime > datetime.now() - timedelta(days = 3)).mean(),
    day_7=(x.datetime > datetime.now() -timedelta(days = 7)).mean())))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create boolean masks before `groupby`, add new columns by [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and `groupby` with `mean`:

```
m1 = df.datetime >  pd.datetime.now() - pd.Timedelta(days = 3)
m2 = df.datetime >  pd.datetime.now() - pd.Timedelta(days = 7)

df = df.assign(day_3=m1, day_7=m2).groupby('stuff')['day_3','day_7'].mean()
```

Comment: doesnt this just give the mean of the day_3 and day_7 column? shouldn't I need to specify I want it to be applied to the "value" column?

Comment: @SuperString If remove `['day_3','day_7']` after groupby it count mean also `value` column. So possible solution should be remove this column afftwt assign like `df = df.assign(day_3=m1, day_7=m2). drop('value', axis=1).groupby('stuff').mean()`